# Payment Processing

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Hoping to get some information from the community, as I've been searching for hours.

We own a platform that processes payments for our vendor/customers in stripe and paypal. Recently, we started to look into processing bitcoin/alt's too - but there seems to be limited information available around the topic.

Using APIs that are available, we can create and receive payments without a problem. But that will put us at the mercy of those platforms, creating a 3rd party nightmare.

What would be the minimal requirements or how would one create a payment solution without using all these other integrations.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe supports bitcoin (see: https://stripe.com/bitcoin) so if you currently use it, that would be a simple step to take.
Otherwise, to be completely independent, you would need to run a full bitcoin node to verify new transactions to the addresses you generate for your customers. Your payment platform can query that node for new addresses, incoming transactions, etc. as well as sending transactions using those incoming inputs

Comment: Yeah, the only problem with that - it's centralized and you have to deal and you don't get or hold actual bitcoin. So, as a crypto support that's not the line I want to take.

The full node, is pretty much what I've been seeing too - using the client qt - the issue we have is linking it to a site. We're not core developers, but I am sure we could in the end figure something out. Would rather have someone handle that part. lol

Appreciate your input.